# I want to remove certain data on pivot table from my JSON output Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two db tables: exercises and schedules. The relation between them is a many to many.
I have some data stored in the pivot table. When i return the table i don't want id to be shown, because it is a useless repetition. The code i'm using:

```
$results =  Schedule::with(['exercises', 'exercises.tags'])->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
        $results->each(function ($schedule) {
            $schedule->exercises->each->makeVisible('pivot');
        });
```

I tried this approach, but it doens't seem to work:

```
$results = $results->toArray();
        foreach ($results as $schedule) {
            foreach ($schedule['exercises'] as $exercise) {
                unset($exercise['pivot']['schedule_id']);
                unset($exercise['pivot']['exercise_id']);
            }
        }
```

I know the question may not be much clear, sorry for that but my english is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

Use the eloquent **makeHidden** method:

```
$results = $results ->makeHidden(['exercises.pivot.schedule_id']);
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-makeHidden

Comment: It doesn't work. I have forgot a detail: the pivot field is hidden by default, so i have to make it visible and after that hide schedule_id and exercise_id, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @giuszeppe I dont undestand... you said that you're trying to remove the pivot field from the output which is hidden by default, so whats the matter, what you actually trying to do??